# How can I share data on twitter with a page on my domain?

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications, twitter

I want to have a share button in my app that will post to twitter like, "I just did this, check it out here www.url.com/whatever"

I have the actual twitter part setup.  What I need to do is somehow get the data from my app to some website.  That is the part I need help with.

Essentially I want the website to look like this.  I don't need to create a whole website as I have one, I just need it to create a page and add data like thsi: http://www.fitocracy.com/view_workout/1308962/

Any ideas how?

Comment: u guess better way is will be get current version of index.html, parse it by hands and put it. how u get-put - just using nsurlconnection for that, it's secured way and can be password protected

Comment: is the data in a database? if it is, then you should use some php to display this data. (sorry for the short answer, since i don't know if your using a database, and what kind of database (e.g. MySQL, SQLite etc.) there isn't much i can say)

Comment: All the data is currently stored locally on the iPhone using core data.  So it would have to somehow get pushed to the website when they "Post to twitter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All external apps use OAuth to authenticate with twitter and then use the twitter APIs to post the tweet to the authenticated account.

For details read here: https://dev.twitter.com/

Here is as sample iphone twitter oauth app on github:

https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone